# WebDriver GWT TabPanel Issue

Tags: gwt, selenium, junit, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to create a WebDriver Test for a GWT application which uses a TabPanel. Clicking on a tab works fine in the IDE (it uses the x-path to find the tab) however I cannot get the tab click working in the JUnit test.

All elements have a debugID including the Tabs (although tab id's do not appear to work even in the IDE) and I'm inheriting `com.google.gwt.user.Debug`. I've attempted to locate by Xpath which is the IDE default.

```
genericElement.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='gwt-debug-mainTabPanel']/div[2]/div/div[6]/div/div")
```

I've tried the code outlined in [the documentation](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabPanel.html#onEnsureDebugId%28java.lang.String%29)

```
genericElement.findElement(By.id("gwt-debug-mainTabPanel-bar-tab6")
```

I've also attempted a `moveToelement`(as `clickAt` is no longer supported) and click but that falls over too(unless I'm misunderstanding it). I'd also like to avoid this as it seems bad practice.

```
 Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
 genericElement = driver.findElement(By.id("gwt-debug-mainTabPanel"));
 Action action = builder.moveToElement(genericElement,400, 370).click().build();
 action.perform();
```

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Moving to arbitrary X,Y
>   coordinates not supported.

I know GWT and Webdriver aren't getting along too well - but I feel like this will have a solution. Can anyone offer any help - has anyone implemented a working Webdriver test in which they  click a tab in a GWT TabPanel?

**EDIT**

I've managed to locate the node using Firebug and xpath locators ( you can add /..to move to the parent gwt-TabLayoutPanelTabInner or add /../.. to mover to grandparent gwt-TabLayoutPanelTabInner and it should still work - it does in the IDE)

```
genericElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'gwt-HTML') and contains(text(),'Users')]"));
```

However not the click doesn't change to the required tab - seems to be a known issue (likely don't need both moveToElement and click(genericElement) - hust giving it a shot)

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(genericElement).click(genericElement).build().perform();
```

[See section 3](http://java.dzone.com/articles/testing-gwt-apps-selenium-or) ....This is fun :)

Comment: have you tried waiting for any expected conditions?

Comment: When you say click on tab doesn't work, what happens?

Comment: Sorry - this question was posted 2 and a half years ago and, while I got close, I was unable to find a full solution. I've moved company and application since then - I don't have the answers to the questions asked.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the tabs are not inside an iFrame?